# NativeScript: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when loading or taking pictures

Tags: android, sqlite, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am building an app for work which loads a picture, either from the gallery or the camera itself, and then displays the image. It works for the first 4-6 images, but then without fail it gives me the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` shown below.

I have searched the forms and have attempted to use `global.gc()` as well as adding:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
android:largeHeap="true"
```

to the android manifest, and even changing the picture size, however, nothing has worked.

I don't know if this is relevant, but I am using `nativescript-sqlite` to store text as well as a reference to where the images are being stored. So maybe someone with experience in sqlite could tell me if sqlite has the ability to produce this type of error.

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated such as how to go about tracking down memory leaks or any other input would be amazing!!

**The Code used to load/take the picture**

There are three methods, the last two call the first one which is where the issue is I believe.

```
public imageProcessing(imageAsset): Promise<any> {
    // Converting it to an ImageSource object
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const source = new ImageSource();

      //It does NOT get past the following line
      // ######################################
      source.fromAsset(imageAsset)
        .then((imageSource: ImageSource) => {
          // Sets the new image to the correct variables
          let base64Picture = imageSource.toBase64String("jpeg", 75);
          this.itemPictureSource = imageSource;
          this.base64_picture_original =  base64Picture;
          // Analyzes the picture
          resolve("Picture finishing analysis");
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("The error is:")
          console.log(err)
          reject();
        })
    })
  }


public onChoosePictureTap(): void {
    this.imageFromLibrary = true
    let context = imagepicker.create({mode: "single" });
    context.authorize().then(() => {
        return context.present();
    })
    .then((selection) => {
      let imageAsset = selection[0]; 
      this.imageProcessing(imageAsset)
    })
  }

private getPicture(): Promise<any> {
    let pictureOptions: CameraOptions = { 
      saveToGallery: true, 
      allowsEditing: true,
      keepAspectRatio: true,
      height: 800,
      width: 600
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      requestPermissions().then(() => {
        // Taking the picture
        takePicture(pictureOptions).then((imageAsset: ImageAsset) => {
            this.imageProcessing(imageAsset)
            .then(() => {   resolve()   })
            .catch(() => {  reject()    })
          }, (error) => {
            reject("Problem with taking a picture")
          });
        },
        () => reject("Camera Permissions rejected")
      );
    })
  }
```

**The bug**

```
AssetPicturePageComp…ent.ngfactory.js:21 
ERROR Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 18662412 byte allocation with 6832792 free bytes and 6MB until OOM
    dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
    android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:613)
    android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:636)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1242)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1122)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1109)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1089)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1081)
    com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onActivityResult(NativeScriptActivity.java:53)
    android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7226)
    android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4521)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4568)
    android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1706)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)

ERROR Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 44769200 byte allocation with 8609656 free bytes and 8MB until OOM
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1242)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1122)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1109)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1089)
    com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1081)
    com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onActivityResult(NativeScriptActivity.java:53)
    android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7226)
    android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4521)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4568)
    android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1706)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: Your images are just too large for Android to handle. Nothing wrong with nativescript specifically. You're just loading very large images which throw the OOM error. You can resize/reduce their file size or use Picasso or other plugins for NS which use native libraries that improve the memory management for images on Android.

Comment: That's what I've read elsewhere, but this code worked before I implemented nativescript-sqlite to store the data (I am not storing the images in sqlite, the images are being stored using the file system)

Comment: Yea, sqlite shouldn't be causing this, 99% of the time OOM with any images being displayed is simply the images are too large and android throws the OOM error. I'd recommend trying this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-image-cache-it and see if that doesn't remedy the issue. Or https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-fresco plugin which uses Facebooks own fresco lib to handle the memory, very well written and I've used it myself.

Comment: Thank you @BradMartin, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to test this out as I switched Frameworks (Flutter) to complete the project on time and add additional features. Thank you for your comments though @BradMartin.